# Problems with solr queries

Tags: solr

when I make a search against Solr in my local machine, I get a query like this:

http://localhost:8080/solr/project/select/?q=concept&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

But instead, I would like to get a complete query with all the settings active, filters, tokeinzer... etc.

For instans, something like this:
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=macrosoft&qt=spellchecker&cmd=rebuild

How can I set up this configuration??? I have tryed a lot of things and no result!! I want to know exaclty how is spellchecker working.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in solrconfig.xml:

```
<str name="echoParams">all</str>
<int name="rows">10</int>
<str name="fl">*</str>
<str name="version">2.1</str>
```